# How to Convert a Text File into a List in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm having trouble trying to convert a text file into a list of lists split by commas. Basically, I want:

```
DATE  OF OCCURRENCE,WARD,LONGITUDE,LATITUDE
06/04/2011,3,-87.61619704286184,41.82254380664193
06/04/2011,20,-87.62391924557963,41.79367531770095
```

to look like:

```
[["DATE  OF OCCURRENCE", "WARD", "LONGITUDE" , "LATITUDE"],
 ["06/04/2011", "3", "-87.61619704286184", "41.82254380664193"],
 ["06/04/2011", "20", "-87.62391924557963", "41.79367531770095"]]
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
row = []
crimefile = open(fileName, 'r')
for line in crimefile.readlines():
    row.append([line])
    for i in line.split(","):
        row[-1].append(i)
```

However, this gets me a result of:

```py
[['DATE  OF OCCURRENCE,WARD,LONGITUDE,LATITUDE\n', 'DATE  OF OCCURRENCE', 'WARD', 'LONGITUDE', 'LATITUDE\n'], 
['06/04/2011,3,-87.61619704286184,41.82254380664193\n', '06/04/2011', '3', '-87.61619704286184', '41.82254380664193\n'], 
['06/04/2011,20,-87.62391924557963,41.79367531770095', '06/04/2011', '20', '-87.62391924557963', '41.79367531770095']]
```

I just want to be able to remove that first part and replace it with the second. How can I do that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Maybe:

```
crimefile = open(fileName, 'r')
yourResult = [line.split(',') for line in crimefile.readlines()]
```

Comment: This works for this simple example, but learn the csv module for data files like this. You'll be glad when you start reading in quote-enclosed string fields that contain commas in the data. (split() is not smart enough to know which commas are separators from those that are inside a quoted string.) Not a problem with this all-numeric data set, but if you learn good practices from the start, you won't have to unlearn the bad ones later.  Also, check out the csv.DictReader class - it will use the first line of your file as key names, and give you a dict for each row instead of just a list.

Comment: @michael: it would be better if you removed the `.readlines()`, because it is (1) unnecessary and (2) uses up memory for nothing.  In fact, you can simply do `[… for line in crimeFile]` and Python will simply iterate over the lines of the file and use almost no memory, instead of using `readlines()`, which reads the whole file into memory and puts all the lines in a list (which uses up memory).

Comment: @michael: This version keeps newline characters in the last line items, which may not be convenient.

Answer (score 15):

This looks like a CSV file, so you could use the python [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) to read it. For example:

```
import csv

crimefile = open(fileName, 'r')
reader = csv.reader(crimefile)
allRows = [row for row in reader]
```

Using the csv module allows you to specify how things like quotes and newlines are handled. See the documentation I linked to above.

Comment: I took a look at the documentation and the code above, but I am still a bit unclear. What exactly does the 3rd line do in your code?

Comment: The third line is a python [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). The `reader` class can be used as an iterable so you can iterate over each of the rows in the csv file. Each row is actually a list containing one value for each column of the csv file. So the third line of the code just says: create a list containing each row of the `reader` iterable. Each row is itself a list of values, so the end result is that `allRows` is a list of lists just as you desired.

Comment: @srgerg: The code above would be better with `allRows = list(reader)`, which does what the more complicated list comprehension `allRows = [row for row in reader]` does.

Answer (score 4):

I believe @michael's comment might be a bit deprecated. Since I have come across this question and it seems to be still relevant I would like to provide a more up to date solution based on that previous response, which would be something like:

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    your_result = [line.split(',') for line in f.read().splitlines()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Going with what you've started:

```
row = [[]] 
crimefile = open(fileName, 'r') 
for line in crimefile.readlines(): 
    tmp = []
    for element in line[0:-1].split(','):
        tmp.append(element)
row.append(tmp)
```

Comment: It is more efficient and clear to write `for line in crimefile:` instead of the unnecessarily memory-consuming `for line in crimefile.readlines()`.

Comment: Also, the `line[0:-1]` does not work as is on Windows, because Windows uses two bytes in order to represent newlines. You would need to open the file in `rU` mode, which converts newlines to `\n`.

Comment: On your first comment - I am aware of that, I just extended his code. On your second comment, line[0:-1] works fine for me on Windows with Python 2.7.2.

Comment: The error might be a little subtle to spot (for instance, the sequence `Hello\r\r\n` looks normal, when printed).  Is the result of `print tmp[-1], len(tmp[-1])` (just after `row.append()`) as expected?

Comment: >>> f = open('eol.txt','r')
    >>> total = []
    >>> for l in f:
    ...     total.append(l)
    ...
    >>> total
    ['test\n']
    >>> t= total[0][0:-1]
    >>> t
    'test'
    >>> print t[-1]
    t
    >>> print len(t[-1])
    1

Comment: Alright.  The (default) text mode in your Python transforms the `\r\n` sequence in the input file into `\n`. From the documentation: "The default is to use text mode, which *may* convert '\n' characters to a platform-specific representation on writing *and back on reading*." (emphasis is mine).  I removed my -1 and put a +1 instead.  It is more usual to write `line[:-1]` than `line[0:-1]`, though. :)