# Calculate Average from Text File in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file that contained list of numbers. In this case, I'd like to calculate average of each three numbers. Any ideas to do this? Thanks before

Example of numbers in text file:

```
5
7
3
10
12
6
```

Output that I want:

```
5
9
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they are each on one line:

```
# text file is myData.txt
averages = {} # using a dictionary so you can keep track of the starting point
with open('myData.txt', 'r') as myFile:
    data = myFile.read().split('\n') # this creates a list of the data
for index in range(len(data), 3): # step of 3
    n = float(int(data[index]) + int(data[index+1]) + int(data[index+2])) / 3
    averages[index] = n
```

This will raise an `IndexError` if the list is not exactly in chunks of 3, so I added in `try`/`except` blocks:

```
# text file is myData.txt
averages = {}
with open('myData.txt', 'r') as myFile:
    data = myFile.read().split('\n') # this creates a list of the data
for index in range(len(data), 3): # step of 3
    try: a = int(data[index])
    except (IndexError, TypeError): a = 0
    try: b = int(data[index+1])
    except (IndexError, TypeError): b = 0
    try: c = int(data[index+2])
    except (IndexError, TypeError): c = 0
    # except (IndexError, TypeError): avoids an error if the end of the list 
    # has been reached or the line is not an integer
    n = float(a + b + c) / 3
    averages[index] = n
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to "parse" the text file and to do this you need to know how it's organized and how it's encoded.  I have a few questions for you first.

1. Will the numbers always be stored with spaces between them?
2. Where do you want this output?  printed to the console?  In a new txt file?

You could od the following

```
#read the file 
my_file = open("C:/numbers.txt",'r')
my_text = my_file.read()
my_file.close()

#get a list of numbers from it (in string form)
my_text_numbers = my_text.split(' ')

#use list comprehension to get integer...also consider
#using map function
my_int_numbers = [int(n) for n in my_text_numbers]

#now the averaging part I will leave to you, I assume it's
#the file reading part you needed help with.
```

Comment: Your `.split()` won't necessarily work-- what if the file looks like `2\n7\n3\n...` and doesn't have any spaces at all?  `my_text.split()` should work, though.

Comment: definitely I agree, that's why I asked if his data was going to be separated by spaces.  In the OP's first post, the data was separated by spaces not by lines.

Answer (score 1):

`data.txt`:

```
5
7
3
10
12
6
```

How to process it using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
In [4]: import numpy as np

In [5]: with open('data.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().split()
   ...:     

In [6]: data
Out[6]: ['5', '7', '3', '10', '12', '6']

In [7]: a = np.array(map(float, data))

In [8]: a
Out[8]: array([  5.,   7.,   3.,  10.,  12.,   6.])

In [9]: b = a.reshape([-1,3])

In [10]: b
Out[10]: 
array([[  5.,   7.,   3.],
       [ 10.,  12.,   6.]])

In [11]: b.sum(1)/3
Out[11]: array([ 5.        ,  9.33333333])
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved by saving the lines of the text file to a list. You also should use the csv module, which can be looked at [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)
    import csv

```
file = open("fileName.txt", 'r')
reader = csv.reader(file)
allRows = [row for row in reader]
```

Then, it should work to take the allRows list, add the values up, and divide by length of allRows. This module I do not know too well, so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205807/how-to-convert-a-text-file-into-a-list-in-python) may explain it better than I do.