# Creating lists from a non-csv .txt file; output to new .txt based on variable conditions

Tags: python, list, csv

I have two quick python questions. This is my first experience with python; I have almost no programming experience whatsoever so I apologize - this is a very basic question and I know it should be easy. I did search for existing answers but could not find anything that helped.

Basically, I have a .txt file that keeps up with 31 variables. There is a header at the top with category names, and then the following lines are just the entries. It looks like this:

```
date time parameter3 ... parameter31
 d1   t1   p3_1      ... p31_1
 d2   t2   p3_2      ... p31_2
```

etc.

All of the parameters are numerical, except for parameter6, which will be either a string of three letters or if it is empty will be "..."

The .txt file is not comma-separated; only one to three whitespaces separate each value.

I am trying to import this text file into Python, create a list out of each line, and then have Python check parameter7 and parameter9. If parameters 7 is <30 and parameter 9 is <35, I want Python to take that entry and output it to a new .txt file. If either of these conditions does not hold, I want it to ignore that particular line and move on. How should I go about writing such a program?

This is the only thing I found that was similar to my problem:
[How to Convert a Text File into a List in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205807/how-to-convert-a-text-file-into-a-list-in-python)

However, the above assumes the .txt file is already comma-separated.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Using line.split() in order to get the fields should work for you.

for example:

```
def line_should_be_stored(fields):
    return int(fields[6]) < 30 and int(fields[8]) < 35

f_out = open('test.txt', 'wt') 
with open('test.txt', 'rt') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        fields = line.split();
        if line_should_be_stored(fields):
            f_out.write(line)
f_out.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Roberto! This gives an output file. How do I tell Python to check for the parameter values that will tell it to hold on to and output the data lines I want? I tried using

`def line_should_be_stored(fields):
    if  line[6] is <30 and line[8] is <35: 
    return True`
as suggested below, but this gives a syntax error (it's probably my bad for not knowing what Python is looking for). What is the appropriate syntax?

Comment: Try to convert then to integer: "if int(line[6]) > 30 ..."

Comment: It still yields a syntax error. Here is what I have:

`def line_should_be_stored(fields):
      if  int(line[6]) is <30 and int(line[8]) is <35: 
    return True

f_out = open('data_sorted.txt', 'wt') 
with open('data.txt', 'rt') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        fields = line.split();
        if line_should_be_stored(fields):
           f_out.write(line)
            
f_out.close()`

Comment: Replace "if  int(line[6]) is <30 and int(line[8]) is <35: return True" by "return int(fields[6]) < 30 and int(fields[8]) < 35"

Comment: Ok, I have the replacement in the code now. For some reason it still outputs just an empty text file. Is there some type of preamble to initiate the code that is needed?

Comment: Put an example of line that should be stored, to figure out why the conditions is not working

Comment: The following is all on one line. It should be saved because of the 12.6 in column 7 and the 34.6 in column 9: `20140108 00:26:11.000 287.442  4 44.06 ...   12.6   0.5   75.9   34.6  20.42  -60.30   0.08  44.28   16.05  46.52   -0.76   1.60   0.39   0.12  15.80 107.44    4.27    0.97    2.23    5.7   35.4  41.089  -81.303  41.208  -81.393`

Comment: According to that, int(line[8]) == 75.9, so doesn't pass the condition. Take in account that you split() using spaces. But this kind of issues you should solve putting some traces, for instance, inside the function, "print (fields[6], fields[8])", so you can see if those indices are the correct ones, or maybe you are using others

Answer (score 0):

create a write method:

```
def write_method(row)
    """
    Note this method will append to an exsisting file, 
    if you do not want that then remove conditional statement below and replace 
    'a' with 'w+' in the with statement.
    """
    if not os.path.isfile('somefile.txt'):
        with open('somefile.txt' 'w+')

    with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
          the_file.write(row)
```

The link you supply is the right answer, you just need to replace :

```
for i in line.split(","):
```

with

```
for i in line.split("   "):
```

This will give you:

["d1", "t1", "p3_1", "...", "p31_1", "d2", "t2",   "p3_2", "...", "p31_2"]

for each line instead of append you can grab "line[6] and line[8]"

```
if line[6] is <30 and line[8] is <35:
    row.append(line)
```

If you require the lines on a new line each time 'row.append(line)' becomes

```
row.append('%s\n' % line)
```

after parsing the file you can then pass row to the file write method

```
 write_method(row)
```