# How can I save output from BeautifulSoup as a csv?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginner with python, and I'm trying to use it to scrape data from: 
https://www.spotrac.com/nfl/arizona-cardinals/sam-bradford-6510/cash-earnings/ (and other such pages)

I really just need the player name (so Sam Bradford here) and then the values for total cash at the end for each year. So basically a table with year and then dollars.

I've used beautifulsoup to get an output, and tinkering around with some code I've got a terminal output in a table looking thing. But my end goal is to save it as a csv or xlsx so I can move it into a program like Stata. And ideally, I'd like to automate this process for every such page on the website.

The code I have so far is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import SoupStrainer
import urllib.request
import csv
import pandas as pd
import requests
from tabulate import tabulate

url = "https://www.spotrac.com/nfl/arizona-cardinals/sam-bradford-6510/cash-earnings/"

markup = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml")

name_box = soup.title.text.strip()
#print(name_box)

earnings_table = soup.find('table', class_ = "earningstable")
#print(earnings_table.get_text())
rows = earnings_table.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols=row.find_all('td')
    cols=[x.text.strip() for x in cols]
    print(cols)

with open('test.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
    #writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer = csv.writer(open("/path/SamBradford.csv", 'w'))
    writer.writerow([name_box, cols])
```

This gets me a csv, but the salary data stuff is all in one column, which isn't helpful.

Any help on how to save this one and then possibly automate it for other pages on the site would be appreciated.

Comment: try `writer.writerow([name_box, *cols])`

Comment: `cols.insert(0, name_box)` and `writerow(cols)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `pandas` it's a great python package for building csv files and tables.

Here's a starting point:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {
        'column a': "row 1 column a",
        'column b': "row 1 column b",
        'column c': "row 1 column c",
    },
    {
        'column a': "row 2 column a",
        'column b': "row 2 column b",
        'column c': "row 2 column c",
    },
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

output `output.csv`:

```
,column a,column b,column c
0,row 1 column a,row 1 column b,row 1 column c
1,row 2 column a,row 2 column b,row 2 column c
```

Comment: Thank you, the pandas thing worked great. I now have a follow up question: if I have all the urls to loop through in a .txt file, how can I use that to loop it (and then save to a file with name_box.csv?)

Comment: You can read in the text file and then assign the data to a variable to use to loop over. So all the URLs will be in a list, and you just loop over the list of URLs as you nor ally would. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205807/how-to-convert-a-text-file-into-a-list-in-python

Comment: Thanks again. So I read in the text file, but the urls are getting redirected to an error page on the site, which leads me to think that they aren't getting read in properly. I don't know what's going on there

Comment: Can you print the URLs as it loops to make sure it's reading in the URLs from the text file correctly"

Comment: Right, when I print it, I get a link to "site.com/error"

Comment: So that must mean there's some bad URLs in your text file?

Comment: No, sorry, I messed that up. I can print the URLs fine, but then when I do the "x=requests.get(url)", I then get the site.com/error when I try to print 
"x.url"

Comment: Hmm, i'm not sure what would cause that. It is possible that they could be blocking your request? I know when I've tried to do similar projects if I use the same URL they sometimes block me for doing too many requests. You could try spoofing your headers so it looks like you're a different user for each request.

Answer (score 0):

Here a possible solution :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import SoupStrainer
import urllib.request
import csv
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://www.spotrac.com/nfl/arizona-cardinals/sam-bradford-6510/cash-earnings/"
markup = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml")
name_box = soup.title.text.strip()
# I use for pandas for parse html tables to csv
# The problem that I found was your table have 2 tbody ...so I decided make a format
# 'find' will find the first tag
earnings_table = soup.find('table', class_ = "earningstable")
tbody = earnings_table.find('tbody')
thead = earnings_table.find('thead')
table='<table>'+str(thead)+str(tbody)+'</table>'
df = pd.read_html(str(table), flavor="bs4")[0]
df.to_csv('test.csv',index=False)
```